# Riemann sum definition of Riemann integrability

Tags: integration

> Suppose that $a>0$ and that $f$ is integrable on $[-a,a]$. Show that if $f$ is even then: $$\int_{-a}^0 f(x) \ {\rm d}x = \int_0^a \ f(x) \ {\rm d}x,$$using the Riemann sum definition of Riemann-integrability.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Choose symmetric partitions: $-a=x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < 0 < \cdots < x_{n-1} < x_n = a$ where $x_k = -x_{n-k}$. Then choose the points where you evaluate $f$ symmetrically as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have tried:
Let P be tagged partition of [-a,0] i.e. -a = x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_k = 0 and P* be the symmetrical tagged partition of [0,a] i.e. 0 = x_k < x_(k+1) < ... < x_2k = a
where x_0=-x_2k, x_1=-x_(2k-1), ... , x_(k-1)=-x_(k+1)

Then I try to prove that S(f;P)=S(f;P*).

Define S(f;P)= Summation from i=1 to k of f(x_i-1)*(x_i - x_(i-1)) and
S(f;P*)= Summation from i=k to 2k of f(x_i)*(x_i - x_(i-1)).
Since f is even i.e. f(x_2k)=f(-x_0)=f(x_0) etc, S(f;P)=S(f;P*).

Does this proof look okay? Did I use and justify the definition correctly here?